# EF Core. Update Entity without update navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to update an Entity EF Core record like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    public int ZoneId { get; set; }
    public virtual Zone Zone { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}
```

When I call Context.Update() or Context.Add(), also update Zone and Country entities. I don't want that the virtual properties update. I am trying, with reflection, get the virtual properties for indicate that Entry(virtualProperty).State = EntityState.Detached, but I can not. This is the code that I am trying.

```
Type typeOfTEntity = typeof(TEntity);
foreach (var property in typeOfTEntity.GetProperties())
{
    if (property.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual)
    {
        foreach (var member in context.Context.Entry(CurrentItem).Members)
        {
            if (member.Metadata.Name == property.Name)
            {
                context.Context.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Detached;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error: "The entity type 'ReferenceEntry' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model."
I use TEntity because I use more entities in a generic Class and use the same method to Update or Add.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
If I use the entity (CurrentItem) like non generic type:
(CurrentItem is now Customer, instead of TEntity)

```
context.Context.Entry(CurrentItem.Country).State = EntityState.Detached;
context.Context.SaveChanges();
```

Now works well. But I need to use TEntity.

Comment: what about mark all navigation properties  `unchanged` like  `context.Context.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Unchanged;`

Comment: The error occurs also when set the state to Unchanged

Comment: what if you make navigation properties `unchanged` directly not via `Reflection`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to set navigation properties to unchanged without reflection.

Comment: can you share how does your model look like?

Comment: Of course, the Customer model is the one that I wrote in the question with other properties (Created Date, Created User... this properties are in all of the entities). I create an instance of TEntity (Customer) or select one of a list of Customers. When new, the Customer's zone is null, but I can select one zone in the form (window). Then asign the zone and ZoneId to the customer. When I save the new customer, I track the changes with the properties "Created date", created user... but this properties are changed also in the Zone entity. I use a repository and a unit of work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. Instead of inserting the property in the Entry, the value of the property had to be inserted.

```
using (var context = new OpenContext<TContext>(connectionString))
{
    var repository = context.UnitOfWork.GetRepository<TEntity, TKey>();
    repository.Update(CurrentItem);

    // Get the type of TEntity
    Type typeOfTEntity = typeof(TEntity);
    foreach (var property in typeOfTEntity.GetProperties())
    {
        // Check the properties that are virtual and not are HashSet
        if (property.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual && property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Count() == 0)
        {
            object value = property.GetValue(CurrentItem);
            // Check that value is not null and value type is an Entity
            if (value != null && value.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Entity<int>)))
            {
                // Set the value that I don't want to change
                context.Context.Entry(value).State = EntityState.Detached;
            }
        }
    }
    context.UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to Update "subentities", you should not Include them when you get the Customer you wan't to update.

Comment: I need to load the navigation entities to show them in the form to binding textboxes with some properties.